# Verse in reledmac

Tags: reledmac, verse

I need to use verses quoted in the middle of a prose text edited with reledmac. If I use the verse environment or quotation the line numbering is misaligned with the verses (though correctly numbered).
Per the section 9.1 of the documentation of reledmac I should use \stanza ending each line withe `&` and `\&` for the last one.
Still I can't get the file compiled.
Latex says:
! Missing number, treated as zero.

\def
l.27    C
olle tumet  \edtext{modico}{\Afootnote{modicum \textit{A}}} lenique exc...

Then it mistakes the & for a tab alignment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}
\lineation{page}
\fnpos{familiar-critical}
\Xlemmafont{\mdseries}


\begin{document}

    
    
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Petrei et Afranei \edtext{clade}{\Afootnote{claue \textit{A}}} haud nobilitata ciuitas de qua Lucanus:
\pend

\pstart
    \stanza
    Colle tumet  \edtext{modico}{\Afootnote{modicum \textit{A}}} lenique excrescit in altum &
    pingue solum tumulo super  hunc fundata  uetusta &
    surgit Ilerda  \edtext{manu}{\Afootnote{mari \textit{A}}}; placidis  praelabitur undis &
    Hesperios inter Sicoris non ultimus amnis &
    saxeus ingenti, quem pons amplectitur arcu &
    Hibernas passurus aquas.\&
\pend

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many beginners with reledmac, you missed to define stanza indentation (§ 9.1 / 9.2 of reledmac handbook).

Also, you don't need any pstart around stanza, as each line of verse in stanza mode is already a pstart.

So you MWE becomes

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}
\lineation{page}
\fnpos{familiar-critical}
\Xlemmafont{\mdseries}
\setstanzaindents{5,1,1}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

\begin{document}



\beginnumbering
\pstart
Petrei et Afranei \edtext{clade}{\Afootnote{claue \textit{A}}} haud nobilitata ciuitas de qua Lucanus:
\pend

    \stanza
    Colle tumet  \edtext{modico}{\Afootnote{modicum \textit{A}}} lenique excrescit in altum &
    pingue solum tumulo super  hunc fundata  uetusta &
    surgit Ilerda  \edtext{manu}{\Afootnote{mari \textit{A}}}; placidis  praelabitur undis &
    Hesperios inter Sicoris non ultimus amnis &
    saxeus ingenti, quem pons amplectitur arcu &
    Hibernas passurus aquas.\&

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact, it is written in bold in the doc: "In order to use the stanza macros, one must set the indentation values." Now it works almost fine. The only problem is that there is no vertical space between the prose text before and after the verse (unlike the environment verse or quotation which leave some space before, at least). Any suggestion?

Comment: I have used ` ``\vspace{3mm}``` in the past, but I noticed  that such spaces (which I used to push a chapter title left in the last line to the next page) were accumulated and then unloaded somewhere further down the document.

Comment: ton insert space, you should use optional argument of \stanza

Comment: which argument should I use then? I read the 9.9 section of documentation that mentions optional arguments of \stanza and says "It is possible to add content, like a subtitle or a spacing, before or after verse:", but I don't figure out how...

Comment: any things that produce space : it can be a vskip, vspace, etc.